# server.transfer is not transferring to the next page when the button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a simple Login form using vb.net when the correct username and password is given the form it is not transferring to the the next page when the button is clicked.And my code is

```
<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
If txtuname.Text="xxx"  AND txtpass.Text="xxx" Then
Response.write("Welcome user")
Server.Transfer("login2.aspx")
Else
Response.write("Invalid Username and Password")
End If
End sub
</script>
```

It is not transferring to the next page.How to resolve this?

Comment: if you want to transfer on button click, move your code to the button click method rather than page_load

Comment: Why is this tagged with dreamweaver and asp.net?